# Grant AWS IAM Group access to a single S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a vendor that needs to upload a CSV file and a ZIP file nightly to an AWS S3 bucket.  Clearly, I don't want them to see/access any of my other buckets.  After a lot of back and forth with them, the only way they can accomplish this nightly task is with the below policy applied to the IAM Group their user is a part of:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is obviously not ideal and I really want their user to have a much more restrictive policy.  I've been testing a bunch of other policies with the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) and they're all resulting in a "Denied - Implicitly denied (no matching statements)" outcome when testing for ListBucket and PutObject.  I have also removed the "Block all public access" setting from the bucket, thinking it was creating the inherent Deny status.

Some of the many policies I have tried are:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And

```
 {
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

And

```
{  
   "Version": "2012-10-17",  
   "Statement": [  
     {  
       "Effect": "Allow",  
       "Action": [  
             "s3:GetBucketLocation",  
             "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"  
            ],  
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"  
     },  
     {  
       "Effect": "Allow",  
       "Action": "s3:*",  
       "Resource": [  
         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",  
         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"  
       ]  
     }  
   ]  
 }
```

Any assistance is appreciated on this.  Thanks in advance for a few minutes of your time.

Comment: Does this vendor access via web console or api/sdk?

Comment: API/CLI.  Sorry, should have clarified that.

Comment: Have you specify the bucket arn for both ListBucket and PutObject that you are simulating? If so, does it match with `mybucket`?

Comment: I had not been specifying the bucket ARN in the simulation.  I just did and it passed.  Is there any reason this wouldn't work if I deploy this policy to the IAM Group?  I'm currently testing with the last one mentioned above.

Comment: You need to post more details about what policies are attached to the IAM group in order for us to debug.

Comment: There are no other policies for the group.

Comment: Ok, any errors when you hit it from the cli?

Comment: I've never tried the CLI.  Not sure how to attempt/test from there.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

This one has been confirmed by my further testing, as well as extensive testing by my vendor, to work as needed.

```
{  
   "Version": "2012-10-17",  
   "Statement": [  
     {  
       "Effect": "Allow",  
       "Action": [  
             "s3:GetBucketLocation",  
             "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"  
            ],  
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"  
     },  
     {  
       "Effect": "Allow",  
       "Action": "s3:*",  
       "Resource": [  
         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",  
         "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"  
       ]  
     }  
   ]  
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that policy would work. I've changed your question title from "Restrict" to "Grant" because that is what you seem to need in this situation (_giving_ access rather than _limiting_ existing access).

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do this for multiple vendors, you can use the policy to restrict access to a particular **path** rather than having to assign one bucket per vendor. See: [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)